# What are these extra provided subckt models?

Tags: ltspice, pspice

At the continues of UCC28C43 subckt model that I’ve downloaded, the following other subckt models are also available. According to explanations, it seems that, they are for simulating the entire flyback schematic. Is it true? And how should I import and use them in ltspice?

```
.SUBCKT FLYBACK_UCC28C4x 1   7   5  4  6 PARAMS: L=12u NC=100 NP=1 RB=6.8 F=190k EFF=1 TS=300n
*               VIN RTN VC VOUT D
*Used for voltage or current mode buck & buck-boost converters.
*{L} primary inductance in Henries
*{NC} current transformer turns ratio
*{NP} Power transformer turns ratio
*{F} switching frequency in Hz
*{EFF} efficiency
*{RB} current transformer burden resistor in ohms
*{TS} propagation delay time in the current loop
*
*B1 IS INPUT CURRENT
GB1 1 7 Value={ V(4)*I(VM1)/(EFF*V(1)) }
*B2 IS PEAK INDUCTOR CURRENT
EB2 2 7 Value={ IF ( V(5) > 0 , (V(5)*NC/(RB))+(V(1)*TS/L) , 0 ) }
*B3 IS MINIMUM INDUCTOR CURRENT
EB3 3 7 Value={ IF ( V(2)-(1/NP*V(4)/(L*F*(1+(1/NP*V(4)/V(1))))) > 0 , V(2)-(1/NP*V(4)/(L*F*(1+(1/NP*V(4)/V(1))))) , 0 ) }
*B4 IS OUTPUT CURRENT
GB4 7 8 Value={ L*F*EFF*(V(2)^2-V(3)^2)/(2*V(4)) }
*B5 IS DUTY CYCLE
EB5 6 7 Value={ IF ( L*F*(V(2)-V(3))/V(1) < 1 , L*F*(V(2)-V(3))/V(1) , 1 ) }
VM1 8 4
.ENDS FLYBACK_UCC28C4x 
*$







.SUBCKT XFMR 1 2 3 4 PARAMS: RATIO=1
* SINGLE WINDING TRANSFORMER 
Rpar 1 2 1MEG
Ea 5 4 VALUE = { V(1,2)*RATIO }
Ga 1 2 VALUE = { I(VMa)*RATIO }
Rser 6 3 1U
VMa 5 6 
RP2 5 0 100Meg
RP3 6 0 100Meg
.ENDS XFMR
*$







.SUBCKT MOC8101 1 2 3   5
* ISOLATOR      A C COL EMITTER
RB 4 0 100Meg
VM 1 6
D1 6 2 LED
H1 7 0 VM .0055
R1 7 8 1K
C1 8 0 3.35nF
G1 3 4 8 0 1
Q1 3 4 5 MPSA06
.MODEL LED D(N=1.7 RS=.7 CJO=23.9P IS=85.3p BV=6 IBV=10U 
+ VJ=0.75 M=0.333 TT=4.32U)
.MODEL MPSA06 NPN (IS=15.2F NF=1 BF=589 VAF=98.6 IKF=90M ISE=3.34P NE=2 
+ BR=4 NR=1 VAR=16 IKR=0.135 RE=0.343 RB=1.37 RC=0.137 XTB=1.5
+ CJE=9.67P VJE=1.1 MJE=0.5 CJC=7.34P VJC=0.3 MJC=0.3 TF=10.29n TR=276N)
.ENDS MOC8101
*$





.SUBCKT XFMRAUX 1    2    3     4     10    11  PARAMS: RATIO_POW=1 RATIO_AUX=1
*Connections     +Pri -Pri +SecP -SecP +SecA -SecA
*Parameters:
* Ratio = Secondary/Primary turns ratio
*
*  1_______   _______3
*    +     ) (          A VsPower
*          ) (_______4   
*    VPrim )  _______10
*          ) (
*    -     ) (          B VsAux
*  2_______) (_______11
*
*  RATIO_POW = 1:A
*  RATIO_AUX = 1:B
*
Rpri 1 2 1MEG
E1 5 4 Value={RATIO_POW*V(1,2)}
G1 1 2 Value={RATIO_POW*I(Vvs)}
Ra 6 3 1U
Vvs 5 6
E2 20 11 Value={RATIO_AUX*V(2,1)}
G2 2 1 Value={RATIO_AUX*I(Vaux)}
Rb2 21 10 1U
Vaux 20 21 
.ENDS XFMRAUX
*$








.SUBCKT MTD1N60E  100 20 30
*     TERMINALS:  D  G  S
LDRAIN  100  10  4.5e-09
M1   1  2  3  3  DMOS L=1U W=1U
RD  10  1  2.80
RS  40  3  0.148
RG  20  2  150
CGS  2  3  218p
EGD 12  0  2  1  1
VFB 14  0  0
FFB  2  1  VFB  1
CGD 13 14  77.0p
R1  13  0  1.00
D1  12 13  DLIM
DDG 15 14  DCGD
R2  12 15  1.00
D2  15  0  DLIM
DSD  3 10  DSUB
LS  30 40  7.50n
.MODEL DMOS  NMOS(LEVEL=1 LAMBDA=2.00m VTO=3.30 KP=0.896
.MODEL DCGD D (CJO=77.0p VJ=0.600 M=0.680
.MODEL DSUB D (IS=4.15n N=1.50 RS=70.0m BV=635
+ CJO=120.3p VJ=0.800 M=0.420 TT=464n
.MODEL DLIM D (IS=100U)
.ENDS MTD1N60E
*$








.MODEL SSR8045 D IS=9.3983E-6 N=1.9085 RS=4.8543E-3
+ CJO=2.8578E-9 M=.3333 VJ=.75
+ ISR=175.46E-6 BV=44.928 IBV=12.938E-3 TT=1.4427E-12
*$



*Diodes,Inc.
.MODEL DI_S1K D ( IS=7.31e-018 
+ RS=42.0m BV=800 IBV=5.00u CJO=42.4p  
+ M=0.333 N=0.775 TT=4.32u) 
*$



* Diodes, Inc.
.MODEL ES3B D (IS=7.27p RS=22.4m BV=100 IBV=10.0u
+ CJO=83.2p  M=0.333 N=0.700 TT=36.0n )
*$



.model MUR160   D(Is=1.043p Rs=74.44m Ikf=2.705m N=1 Xti=2 Eg=1.11 Cjo=28.43p
+       M=.6225 Vj=.75 Fc=.5 Isr=7.011n Nr=2 Tt=123.3n)
*$



.model MBR140P  D(Is=2.835u Rs=47.12m Ikf=.3227 N=1 Xti=0 Eg=1.11 Cjo=302.5p
+       M=.7206 Vj=.75 Fc=.5 Isr=16.98u Nr=2)
*$
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Why do you ask the same question more than once?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen they are not the same. Read carefully.

Comment: Same import but with variables declared to use . VIN RTN VC VOUT D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That model looks to be an averaged model, good for `.AC` analysis. You won't get any switching behaviour, but you'll be able to perform a stability analysis, and maybe even a `.TRAN` response without the high frequency content.